# Offset after projection from WGS84 to ETRS1989

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3

I'm using ArcMap 10.3, my dataframes coordinate system is "ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N_6Stellen". I have several shapefiles in my project which are using the WGS84 system. When I try to proct them to ETRS1989 the output shapefile has an offset of about 0,16 m compared to the original shape (red is the orginal WGS84 shape, green the ETRS one).

[image: Resulting offset]

This is what I entered in the projection tool:

[image: Projections settings]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you also set the same transformations in ArcMap?

Comment: @mkennedy I'm not sure if I get you right but if you are talking about the Transformations I can choose in the Data Frame Properties the answer is: YES.

Comment: I have to correct myself! I did NOT use the same transformations in ArcMap, shame on me... After changing the transormations in ArcMap everything works as expected, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to choose the same transformations in the dataframes properties and in the "Project" tool like suggested by mkennedy.